# Django: return count of items after filter is applied in ListView

Tags: django

I want to render the total items for a filtered queryset.

I've a model `UnitaryProduct` and I can return the total of items with:

```
context['total_stickers'] = UnitaryProduct.objects.all().count()
```

Inside `get_context_data`, but I wouldlike to also return the particular amount of items when users apply a filter by category. This is how I filter items based on user selection:

This is the `ListView`, `get_queryset` I've a condition to use the captured `filter_val`:

```
class CatalogoListView(ListView):

    model = UnitaryProduct
    template_name = "shop/catalogo.html"
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        filter_val = self.request.GET.get('filtro', 'todas')
        order = self.request.GET.get('orderby', 'created')
        if filter_val == "todas":
            context = UnitaryProduct.objects.all().filter(available=True).order_by('-created')
            return context
        else:    
            context = UnitaryProduct.objects.filter(
                subcategory2=filter_val,
            ).filter(available=True).order_by('-created')
            return context

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CatalogoListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filtro'] = self.request.GET.get('filtro', 'todas')
        context['orderby'] = self.request.GET.get('orderby', 'created')
        context['category'] = Category.objects.get(slug="catalogo")
        context['total_stickers'] = UnitaryProduct.objects.all().count()

        return context
```

I've tried to put add `stickers_por_categoria` to the queryset but nothing gets rendered in template:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        filter_val = self.request.GET.get('filtro', 'todas')
        order = self.request.GET.get('orderby', 'created')
        if filter_val == "todas":
            context = UnitaryProduct.objects.all().filter(available=True).order_by('-created')
            return context
        else:    
            context = UnitaryProduct.objects.filter(
                subcategory2=filter_val,
            ).filter(available=True).order_by('-created')
            context['stickers_por_categoria'] = UnitaryProduct.objects.filter(
                subcategory2=filter_val,
            ).filter(available=True).order_by('-created').count()
            return context
```

**template:**

```
<div class="margin-bottom5">
<h2> Actualmente contamos con {{ total_stickers }} stickers en nuestro catálogo</h2>
<span>Revisa todos utilizando nuestro filtro por categoría y la páginación del lado derecho.</span>
<p>Agrega todos los que quieras a tu carrito de compras que nosotros los enviaremos hasta tu domicilio &#128513;.</p>
<h1>{{ stickers_por_categoria }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Would an {{ object_list.count }} tag on the template do the trick?

Comment: Ty but not, that return the "displayed" items, and as pagination is set to 10, it return 10. I would need to return the total items for the filtered `UnitaryProduct` regardless of pagination.

Comment: Maybe pass a variable to get_context_data like:
context['product_count'] = self.get_queryset().count()

Comment: @Samer that worked. ty.